# Populate a dropdown list based on the selection of previous dropdown list using ajax and JSP Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I  wants to develop a live project for one consultancy.
I need a help...
develop JSP page.

1:  user want to select Cilent(Company name) from dropdown list and populating HR list to another dropdown list from belongs to Client(Copmany Name) using ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so whats stopping u..??

Answer (score 0):

On Select of company name get the Id of the company and pass it to server through ajax. On receive of the result json create html code for the drop down and place inside the desired placeholder. 
You can initiate the ajax request using the onChange method jquery.